# What can I use to output a digital audio signal from my computer

Tags: optical-cable, dolbydigital

I want to get something for my laptop to output a digital sound signal to my stereo receiver. My laptop doesn't have a digital optical out or HDMI out, but it does have 3 USB ports and a headphone/mic port. What can I use to output a digital signal?

Comment: I've done a quick search on google. All I found were professional audio devices and cheap DSPs with volume knobs on them. All I want is something I can plug into my computer via USB that outputs either a 2 channel PCM signal or a 5.1 Dolby Digital Signal via an optical cable. I want to use my computer as another digital input signal for my stereo receiver.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Optical out is called "Toslink", which may help your searching. A thread of advice here: https://www.jwz.org/blog/2018/04/usb-to-toslink/

Personally I recommend a Behringer UCA202 - it does have a lot more than you need but it's professional gear at home user prices. However there's some discussion on message boards that it only does 44.1kHz stereo and isn't actually capable of 5.1 Dolby out. You may need to check for 48kHz output.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. This is almost what I'm looking for. The only thing it's missing is a Dolby Digital out format. My stereo can accept a 2 channel signal all day and use Pro Logic to expand it. But for the cases when I have an SACD formated in 5.1 channel audio, or a song in AC-3 encoded in 5.1 channel, I want to be able to throw the signal over a toslink cable to my stereo. In which my stereo has an auto-detection that can identify and properly output either PCM, Dolby Digital 5.1, or DTS 5.1.

Comment: I searched for one that converts USB to 5.1 and have found one on parts master. Thanks for the help